# Passing events from nested children(s) to parent in Vue

Tags: vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

Im working on a Vue component that will be re-used in different projects (and will be available via `npm install ...`) and have principal question how the event emitting is handled.

The component itself contains few nested children elements like:

```
component-parent
  |-child 1
  |-child 2
      |-child 3
         |-child 4
```

When the component is included in some project then `component-parent` will expose all events that are emitted from the whole component. And was wandering how the in-component events are passed to the `component-parent`. For example if i want to pass event from `child 4` to `component-parent` then `child 4` emits to `child 3` which emits to `child 2` which finally emits to `component-parent`.

Such workflow is working fine but it doesn't look very practical.

Ive found out that `EventBus` can be used and seems more elegant solution but also seems that its not very popular. Is `EventBus` can be used freely or its considered to be a bit hacky/workaround way?

And another question regarding using `vuex`. If `vuex` is included in the component itself is it possible to emit from it to the project component (that have my component included)? Including `vuex` in my component will lead the main project to have two `vuex` instances. Is there are blockers for having multiple stores like this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some testing I've decided to go with `EventBus`. `EventBus` allows sending/receiving events between components. The components can be part of the same parent tree or on a complete different one. More information [here](https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/)

But in general `event-bus.js` file should be created

```
import Vue from 'vue';
export const EventBus = new Vue();
```

And then imported in any component that will use the `EventBus` mechanism

```
<script>
// Import the EventBus we just created.
import { EventBus } from './event-bus.js';
...
```

Then from the sending component emit the event

```
EventBus.$emit('i-got-clicked', this.clickCount);
```

Any component that have loaded `EventBus` can listen for events like this:

```
EventBus.$on('i-got-clicked', clickCount => {
  console.log(`Oh, that's nice. It's gotten ${clickCount} clicks! :)`)
});
```

To stop listen for events:

```
EventBus.$off('i-got-clicked');
```

Personally i find `EventBus` quite easy and useful but I'll probably use them only when developing components that will be included in another projects. For the same project components `Vuex` is more than enough